# setDataSource on a null object reference

Tags: java, android-studio

Logcat is telling me that the uri is null, but I did a toast and it isn't null.How do I fix this?

LogCat:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(android.content.Context, android.net.Uri)' on a null
```

code:

```
public void playSong() {
        uri = Uri.parse(PlayingScreen_List.get(position).getPath());
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this,uri);// **----->> Error is happening here**
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(uri), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);
        }else{
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

Comment: And what about `mediaPlayer`?

Comment: I call create on the Media player after I call "setDataSource" so........when  I call "setDataSource" The media player is null at that point.